# Show/Hide div in a rendered list with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to learn Vue, and I am still quite new to it.

I have a rendered list. In each item, I have a button that I'd like to show/hide a div in that item.

I tried doing the Conditional Rendering in Vue's documentation (https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html), but that toggles the hidden div for every item in the list at once. I'm assuming that's because in the export data, it's returning one variable, whereas I'd need an item specific variable.

**Template Code:**

```
<template>
    <div v-for="time in times">

        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-item">
                <strong>Time:</strong><br>
                <h5>{{ time.date_time }}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item">
                <strong>Is Reserved: </strong><br>
                <h5>{{ time.is_reserved }}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item">
                <button @click="isVisible = !isVisible">Toggle Hidden Area</button>
            </div>  
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div v-if="isVisible">Hidden by Default</div>
            </div>
        </div>
            
    </div>
</template>
```

**Script Code:**

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

    export default {
        name: 'Times',
        props: {
            times: Array
        },
        data() {
            return {
            times: [],
            isVisible: false
            }
        },
        async created() {
                axios
                    .get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/appointments/2022/3/13')
                    .then(response => (this.times = response.data))
        },
        methods: {
            
        }
    }
</script>
```

Am I going the correct route with this? Any advice to get this to work would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a prop called ```times``` and also a data called ```times```. I do not think that is a good practice to give them the same name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want every item to have its own `isVisible` prop, you can't use a global one. You'll need to assign an individual prop to each item, after you get them from the server. Example:

```html
<script>
export default {
  // ....
  created() {
    axios
      .get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/appointments/2022/3/13')
      // mapping isVisible to each item, dynamically:
      .then(response => (this.times = response.data.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        isvisible: false
      }))));
  }
  // ....
}
</script>
<template>
  <div>
     <div v-for="(time, key) in times" :key="key">
       <!-- ... -->
       <div class="grid-item">
         <button @click="time.isVisible = !time.isVisible">Toggle Hidden Area</button>
       </div>
       <div class="grid-item">
         <div v-if="time.isVisible">Hidden by Default</div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

**Notes:**

- you can't have more than one root HTML element in Vue2 components (technically, you can, but you'd need to use a render function - let's say it gets complicated fairly quickly)
- I only wrote what you need to change, not the entire component.
- as @hamid-davodi has rightly pointed out in his comment, you currently have `times` defined in both `data` and `props`. You need to rename one of them (vue should warn you about it).

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much helping, and the tips.